# _hashlib module not available - PyPy3

Tags: python

I have downloaded and un-tared pypy3 (pypy3.6-v7.1.1-linux64). I got it to run the interpreter from inside the folder

```
$ ./pypy3.6-v7.1.1-linux64/bin/pypy3
```

However, when I run my code (which is to be run in parallel) I get the following warning message:

```
/mnt/irisgpfs/users/yomar/pypy3.6-v7.1.1-linux64/lib-python/3/hashlib.py:172: RuntimeWarning: The _hashlib module is not available, falling back to a much slower implementation (libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
  RuntimeWarning)
```

This issue makes my code much slower and defeats the whole purpose of using pypy. Can anyone suggest a solution?

I am running this on an HPC cluster, where I am loading a module containing Python 3.6.4 and then starting pypy.

Comment: Is libssl installed on the HPC cluster?